# Why can't Community offer bounties to unanswered questions?

Tags: discussion

I read about [Community](https://superuser.com/users/-1/community), and wondered:

#### Why can't Community offer bounties to old, unanswered questions and bring these questions back to life?

Comment: Feel free to revert my edit if you think it was too much.

Comment: Seems like it already does: http://superuser.com/users/-1/community?tab=bounties

Comment: @Oliver Those will be bounties that had been placed by accounts that have since been deleted (as is the case with pretty much everything "owned" by a community user) - see [this](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/139533/how-does-the-community-user-set-bounties) MSO post for the bounty case.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It actually does something already to put questions back to life. It "pokes" 2 unanswered questions per hour, bringing them to the front page.

Bounties are something special, it actually costs part of someone's reputation to "feature" the questions. If the Community user was giving bounties here and there, it would lower the value of the other bounty questions, and reduce their visibility.